# PHP add items from for loop to an object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm sure this is trivial to an expert, I just don't know how to do it exactly.

I have a for loop

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= $picCount; $x++) {
    $finalUrl = $picUrl.$gsi.'&picfilename='.$vin.'_'.sprintf('%03d', $x) .'.jpg';
}
```

What I want to do is add each $finalUrl to the object or an array. How do I do that?

Example of final object:

```
stdClass Object
(
  [title] => Blah
  [test] => w00t!
  [picUrl] => array(
        http://example.com/image/xx1.jpg
        http://example.com/image/xx2.jpg
        http://example.com/image/xx3.jpg
        http://example.com/image/xx4.jpg
     )
)
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the result you want to get.

Comment: Added an example. Please excuse the bad formatting....

Comment: So you are basically asking how to add a value to an array? Have you read any [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) or at least [searched Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+add+value+to+array)?

Comment: @FelixKling. I did, but I am looking to add an array from a for loop. I couldn't find what I was looking for

Comment: It doesn't matter from *where* an element is added from. The loop is irrelevant. If `$foo` is an array, then `$foo[] = $bar;` or `array_push($foo, $bar)` will append an element to that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set `$finalUrl` as an array:

```
$finalUrl = [];
for ($x = 1; $x <= $picCount; $x++) {
    $finalUrl[] = $picUrl.$gsi.'&picfilename='.$vin.'_'.sprintf('%03d', $x) .'.jpg';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray = array();     // Will contain a list of $finalUrl
for ($x = 1; $x <= $picCount; $x++) {
    $finalUrl = $picUrl.$gsi.'&picfilename='.$vin.'_'.sprintf('%03d', $x) .'.jpg';
    $newArray[] = $finalUrl;
}
```

$newArray is the array of $finalUrl's created in the prior loop.
print_r($newArray) will display it's contents.

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming in the end you want an array of strings, this can be easily accomplished doing:

```
$a = [];
for ($x = 1; $x <= $picCount; $x++) {
    $finalUrl = $picUrl.$gsi.'&picfilename='.$vin.'_'.sprintf('%03d', $x) .'.jpg';
    $array[] = $finalUrl
}

return $a;
```

This will return an array of every `$finalUrl` values.

Breakdown:

`$a = []` Initializes an array.

`$a[] = $finalUrl` Pushes $finalUrl to the array